# JSON data in PUT request in C#

Tags: c#, json, put, javascriptserializer

I am trying to make a PUT request with a C# client, this request has JSON data in it.

I use this, which I got from here: [Passing values to a PUT JSON Request in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248935/passing-values-to-a-put-json-request-in-c-sharp)

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(new 
{
    reg_FirstName = "Bob",
    reg_LastName = "The Guy"
});
```

Ofcourse, the Json string looks like this:

```
  {
    "reg_FirstName":"Bob",
    "reg_LastName":"The Guy"
  }
```

But how would I go around creating a JSON string like this:

```
  {
    "main": {
        "reg_FirstName": "Bob",
        "reg_LastName": "The Guy"
    },
    "others": [
        {
            "reg_FirstName": "Robert",
            "reg_LastName": "The Guy"
        },
        {
            "reg_FirstName": "Rob",
            "reg_LastName": "The Guy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same way - dynamic objects, so in your case it would look like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json =
    serializer.Serialize(
        new {
            main = new
            {
                reg_FirstName = "Bob", 
                reg_LastName = "The Guy"
            },
            others = new[]
            {
                new { reg_FirstName = "Bob", reg_LastName = "The Guy" }, 
                new { reg_FirstName = "Bob", reg_LastName = "The Guy" }
            }
        }
    );
```