# How to make PUT API request via C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am trying to create a mobile game app that is going to have a simple login system in the beginning of the game. I created my Rest API in PHP. It works properly. I created my simple GUI in Unity via C#. I made my Api Key authentication successfully. Now I want to insert user's email address and password into my database. I want to model Rest Console Request Payload(Raw Body) so I can simple pass JSON value and insert them into my database like:

```
  {
       "username" : "daredevil",
       "password": 12345
  }
```

I found this links but I don't think that is what I exactly want to do.

[How to make a HTTP PUT request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140674/how-to-make-a-http-put-request)

[Passing values to a PUT JSON Request in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248935/passing-values-to-a-put-json-request-in-c-sharp)

This is my ParseAuthenticate() method in Login.cs class that makes the connection to my API:

```
 public void ParseAuthenticate()
 {
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Login.ValidateRemoteCertificate); // verifying ssl used for login with ServicePoint connection management
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

    try
    {
        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://createAccountURL/register");  //making a request to URL
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.Method= "PUT";

        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add  ("api-key:"+"12334566778");

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream newStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.Log (responseText);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }

}
```

This is my CreateAccountGUI() method that gets username, password, confirm username, confirm password

```
void CreatAccountGUI()
{
    GUI.Box (new Rect(280,120,(Screen.width/4)+200,(Screen.height/4)+250), "Create Account");


    GUI.Label(new Rect(390,200,220,23),"Username");
    CUser = GUI.TextField(new Rect(390,225,220,23), CUser);

    GUI.Label(new Rect(390,255,220,23),"Password");
    CPassword = GUI.TextField(new Rect(390,280,220,23), CPassword);

    GUI.Label(new Rect(390,310,220,23),"Confirm Username");
    ConfirmUser = GUI.TextField(new Rect(390,340,220,23), ConfirmUser);

    GUI.Label(new Rect(390,370,220,23),"Confirm Password");
    ConfirmPass = GUI.TextField(new Rect(390,400,220,23), ConfirmPass);

    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(370,460,120,25), "Create Account"))
    {
        if(ConfirmPass == CPassword && ConfirmUser == CUser)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CreateAccount ());
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(LoginAccount());
        }
    }
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(520,460,120,25),"Back"))
    {
        CurrentMenu = "Login";
    }
}//End CreateAccountGUI
```

And this is my IEnumerator CreateAccount() method:

```
  IEnumerator CreateAccount()
  { 
    Debug.Log ("Button Pressed");
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();

    form.AddField ("Email", CUser);
    form.AddField ("Password", CPassword);

    WWW CreateAccountWWW = new WWW (CreateAccountUrl);
    //wait for php to send something back to Unity
    yield return CreateAccountWWW;

    if (CreateAccountWWW.error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError ("Cannot connect to Account Creation");
    } 
    else
    {
        string CreateAccountReturn = CreateAccountWWW.text;

        if (CreateAccountReturn == "Success")
        {
            Debug.Log ("Success: Account Created!");
            CurrentMenu = "Login";
        }
    }
}//End CreateAccount
```

When I run my Unity I get this "Cannot connect to Account Creation". Can anyone assist me with this PUT method?

Comment: That's a big wall of code I don't want to read, but I will point out that `Login.cs` does not appear to reference the API key at all, other than declaring it. How is the server supposed to know you have the key if you don't send it?

Comment: Don't use unity tag as it is not the unity you refer to.

Comment: what is wrong with the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140674/how-to-make-a-http-put-request ?

Comment: you might also want to use the [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) and check and see what `CreateAccountWWW.error` is

Comment: Sam I am- I actually don't know how and where I am gonna implement it.

Comment: When I use Debug.Log(CreateAccountWWW.error); I get Null because there is no data insert for username and password. By the way I wanna thank everybody for their time and attention.