# how to send http post with json body and url params?

Tags: java, json, http, post

I saw this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request).

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "John"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

and

```
String json = "{"id":1,"name":"John"}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

I want to send a POST http request with json in the body and url params

If I follow the example in the tutorial,

will the second `setEntity` override the first `setEntity` ?

if so, how should I write this?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? You are already sending a ``UrlEncodedFormEntity`` in the first code, you cannot send any json on top of it. So yes, the second ``setEntity`` overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setEntity` just sets the current entity, and does not append to it like the `setHeader` method does.

HTTP does not allow POSTing multiple entities, which is what you are trying to do.

I would suggest compiling all of the data into one JSON `StringEntity`, and then sending that, or just adding everything to the `UrlEncodedFormEntity`

```
String json = "{"username":"John", "password":"pass", "id":1, "name":"John"}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity)
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

or

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "John"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "John"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
```

Answer (score -1):

Guess httpPost is a WebRequest type.

> will the second setEntity override the first setEntity?

Yes, it will.

to make a post request, you should do this:

```
httpPost.Method = "POST";
```

To set a Json object in body, look at the responses to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248935/passing-values-to-a-put-json-request-in-c-sharp).

```
string serializedObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(serializedObject);
}
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```