# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() errors with a 401 error (Unauthorized)

Tags: json.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to do an HTTP PUT request, but am receiving a 401 error (Unauthorized). Here is my code:

```
string token = "<token>"; 
string putUrl = "https://<url>;
string payload = "{grading_standard_id:166}";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(putUrl);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + token;
request.Method = "PUT";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
try
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(serializedObject);
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // ERROR LINE
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.Message;
    throw ex;
}
```

The line that fails is:

```
HTTPWebResponse response = (HttpWebRequest)request.GetResponse();
```

The code sets up a header on the request object with an authorization token; I don't understand why that isn't authenticating here. I tried changing the authentication of the request object to,

> request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; request.PreAuthenticate = true;

just before I do the GetResponse() call, but this error'd out, saying the settings cannot be changed after a stream write.

I took most of this code from another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248935/passing-values-to-a-put-json-request-in-c-sharp). After searching with google a while I have found nothing that helps. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there documentation for the web API you are calling?  If so, what does it say as to how you should be authenticating?

Comment: Yes, it's located [here](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html). The simple authentication method is to obtain an authorization token (which I have done) and specify it in the httprequest.headers attribute (which I have also done in the code).

Comment: The documentation isn't geared towards c#. It's geared towards curl. I can do the task using curl, but I need to do it programmatically. I have tried it from a third party testing tool (Telerik Test Studio for APIs) - it returns a 200 status code but then returns the contents of the object I'm trying to update and the specific attribute ("grading_standard_id" is unchanged). The documentation says that for PUT requests, parameters can be sent in JSON format. I have tried this ({"grading_standard_id":166}) to no avail. Can someone review the documentation (link above) about "updating a course"?